# xaml line 0 "the type mainwindow not found"

Tags: vb.net, xaml

Error XLS0414 in visual studio, The type "MainWindow" not found.

I opened the project one day and this error greeted me. Everything still seems to work fine? I'm just at a loss how to get it to go away. The name of the xaml file is MainWindow.xaml, there is a MainWindow.xaml.vb file, and the opening line to the xaml is "Window x:Class="MainWindow" which it's always had.

I'm very new to visual studio/vb/xaml, how can I fix this or make sure all reference assemblies are built? (VS's suggestion)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Build your project/solution, that error should go away.

Comment: Well the error was gone when I came into work today, but I'll try that if it comes back. Thank you.